# UK student visa FD as financial proof?

Tags: visas, uk, study

I have my financial document as a Certificate of Fixed Deposit under my mothers name and have put my name for bank statement in the application for my UK student visa. Will i be rejected? I will be using the Certificate in conjunction with my joint account with my mother.

Answer (score 3):

If we are talking about Tier 4 student visa here (information from [Tier 4 student visa checklist](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/tier-4-student-visa-checklist)):

> UKVI **will accept money that is frozen in a certificate of deposit**. However the certificate of deposit must prove that the money has already been held for 28 day period which ends within the 31 day period before you paid your visa fee online. For example, if you deposited your funds in a fixed-term account on 1 March, and your date of online application was 15 August, it is not enough to only submit the original deposit slip from 1 March. You must also submit an additional certificate of deposit to show that the money was still held between 15 July and 15 August i.e. within the 31 day period before your online application date.
>
> Funds must be held in your name or **by your parents** or an official sponsor.
>
> You must prove your relationship to your parents if the above funds are held under a parent’s name. You can submit one of the following original documents: birth certificate or adoption certificate. And a letter from your parent(s) or legal guardian(s) providing consent for you to use the money if the above funds are held in their name(s).